# Display the text from database

Tags: html, node.js, arrays, postgresql, express

I want to see on page all text that is saved in database, but i want it to be like a list of text example

- That the first text from data base
- Here is the second one.

I try like this:

```
app.get('/readtext', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const document = await client.query("SELECT text FROM document");
    let variable = document.rows.map(row => row.text).join("\n");
    res.send(variable);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

and my output is:
That the first text from data base  Here is the second one.
i went it to be like this
That the first text from data base

- Here is the second one.
  with or wihtout "*" the ideea is any line from database be on a new line

i use node.js

Comment: Wouldn't that be join("<br>") on a web page.

Comment: OK I added as an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

On a web page you need to use br tag instead of just \n:

```
app.get('/readtext', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const document = await client.query("SELECT text FROM document");
    let variable = document.rows.map(row => row.text).join("<br>");
    res.send(variable);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be to just send an array where each element is the text of each row. In your code that would be:

```
app.get('/readtext', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const textArray = [];
    const document = await client.query("SELECT text FROM document");
    document.rows.map(row => {
      textArray.push(row.text);
    });
    res.send(textArray);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Of course you will need to make tha right adjustments to the front end.